# How do I get a URL link to open in a new window once clicked

Tags: url

I have a URL to an external website within one my site's pages.  I want this to open in a new window.  I don't want the viewer to move off our website but will want them to click on the link to our third party.
How do I get the link to open in a new window?
thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a very general HTML 101 question.

Comment: Thank you.  But please bear in mind that not everyone on here is a HTML expert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `target="_blank"` to the link.

Like so: `<a href="http://google.com" target="_blank">Opens in new window</a>`

Comment: Thank you for your reply.   I have tried this but as the section I need to edit is a button link it doesn't accept HTML and the CMS doesn't allow me to see the HTML editor in that section of entries.  We only access the CMS to make small amendments and the developer didn't help us much.

Comment: Even if this the solution to your question (which is indeed off-topic) the devs maybe have their reasons to not open the link in a new tab/window. However, if the user wants to open the link in a new tab he is probably smart enough to use `Ctrl+Click` or sth. Take a look at this one: https://www.jitbit.com/alexblog/256-targetblank---the-most-underestimated-vulnerability-ever/